# Filter list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, filter

So, I need to build a filter that basically takes the following information...

```
dictlist = [{'ext': 'mp4',
                 'height': 480,
                 'id', 'pies'},
                {'ext': 'webm',
                 'height': 360,
                 'id', 'pies2'},
                {'ext': 'mp4',
                 'height': 360,
                 'id', 'charles1'},
                {'ext': 'mp4',
                 'height': 720,
                 'id', 'tucker'}]
```

(there's more stuff there, but this is simplified)

And then outputs the id of the element that is both an mp4 (or whatever I want. I'm aiming for a function or, alternative, to use built-in stuff to be more python-y if it exists) and has the highest height below a value.

For example, I'd like to build a function that is similar to...

```
def getmestuff(listofdics, extrequired, heightmax):
    /*do the work*/
    return id;
```

So for example using the above data...

```
getmestuff(dictlist, 'mp4', 720)
```

Would return... pies

Comment: Probably should just iterate through it and check your conditions.

Comment: it would return tucker no?

Comment: Bad wording. I want a 'below' value rather than a 'equal to or lower'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

how about this:

```
mp4s = (d for d in dictlist if d['ext'] == 'mp4')
max(mp4s, key=lambda x: x['height'])
```

This will return the "max" dictionary -- From there getting the `id` is easy.  (and you could easily inline the `mp4s`, but I've broken it into 2 lines for clarity.)

---

A little less easy to read, but more compact:

```
max(dictlist, key=lambda d: (d['ext'] == 'mp4', d['height']))
```

The first version will also helpfully raise a `ValueError` if there are no mp4's in the list whereas the second version will just return the thing with the biggest height in that case.

Comment: This does not account for the max height.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error at the in. Is this Python 2.7 compatible?

Comment: @VardaElbereth -- Sorry, typo.  While we're at it, your example data has some syntax errors too (`,` instead of `:`)

Comment: Haha. Thanks so much! Yeah, I sorta made it by hand. Or tried to. The actual data is enormous, so I couldn't copy/paste.

Comment: Also, I should say, I've been doing work in C# and Python and while a lot of the commenters on the C# questions have been SUPER mean and nasty and condescending, everyone who's answered on Python so far has been absolutely wonderful and kind. You guys are great <3.

Comment: Oh, but how would we capture the maxheight though? Currently it just finds the max overall rather than the max below a value.

Comment: Oh, I must have misread the question.  `(d for d in dictlist if d['ext'] == 'mp4' and d['height'] <= maxheight)`

Comment: Got it! mp4s = (d for d in dictlist if d['ext'] == 'mp4' and d.has_key('height') and d['height'] < 720) then max(mp4s, key=lambda x: x['height'])

Comment: Haha I got it literally 10 seconds after you commented. Thanks for your help though. I'll mark it correct =)

Answer (score 0):

A function to do the same:

```
def get_me_stuff(dict_l, val, max_h):
    best = 0
    id = None
    for d in dict_l:
        h = d.get('height')
        if d.get("ext") == val and max_h > h > best:
            best = h
            id = d.get("id")
    return id
```